# Trying to get values out of an array

Tags: php, codeigniter

My model:

```
class Biz_model extends Model{

    function allInfo(){
        $q = $this->db->get('negocios');

        if($q->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($q->result() as $row){
                $data[] = $row;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
}
```

my controller:

```
$this->load->model('biz_model');
            $data['biz'] = $this->biz_model->allInfo();
```

and I'm trying to get the field values on my view by doing:

```
<?php echo $biz->nombre; ?>
```

but so far it isn't working like that or any variations of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model is returning an array of rows, so in your view you need to loop through the array in order to get at the rows' fields:

```
<?php foreach ($biz as $b) : ?>
<?php echo $b->nombre; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```